# How to use Microsoft OCR Library ( Microsoft.Windows.Ocr ) in an ASP.Net MVC4 Web API Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ocr, microsoft-ocr

#### TL;DR:

**Does anyone know of a way to reference `Microsoft.Windows.Ocr` (/ `WindowsPreview.Media.Ocr.dll` ) Assembly on a server-side ASP.Net Web application like MV4 Web API and make use of the OCR Functionality in that assembly to take a photo image as input and extract the text content out of it ?** *If yes, please provide detailed instructions in your answer.*

#### Question Details (and what I have tried so far)

I am building a web application that takes an image uploaded to the Server (via a file upload UI screen) and then reads the text using **OCR** and displays the text on the next page, right next to the image that was uploaded.

Since most commercial OCR Libraries cost an arm and length ([over $1,300 last time I checked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_optical_character_recognition_software)) I thought I can try and use the **Microsoft OCR Library** `Microsoft.Windows.Ocr` that is **FREE** and seems to be [very simple](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/09/18/microsoft-ocr-library-for-windows-runtime/) and straightforward to use.

So I tried to install the **Microsoft.Windows.Ocr** Nuget Package to my ASP.Net MVC4 Web API Project and that succeeded.

[image: install the Microsoft.Windows.Ocr Nuget Package]

After that, I looked through my MVC4 Web API Project References, and to my surprise, did not find a reference to **Microsoft.Windows.Ocr.dll** Assembly.

[image: reference to Microsoft.Windows.Ocr.dll missing]

So then I tried to add a reference to the x86 version of the Microsoft.Windows.Ocr.dll Assembly by browsing to that Assembly in the `\packages` folder, and selected the **WindowsPreview.Media.Ocr.dll** from `\lib\win81\x86` folder

**Note:** The Assembly name is WindowsPreview.Media.Ocr.dll and not  Microsoft.Windows.Ocr.dll , not sure why!

[image: browse to and select Microsoft.Windows.Ocr.dll OCR Assembly]

When I did that and clicked **OK**, I got the following **Error Message**.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
A reference to   
'D:\TestProjects\packages\Microsoft.Windows.Ocr.1.0.0\lib\win81\x86\
 WindowsPreview.Media.Ocr.dll' could not be added. Please make sure 
 that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly 
 or COM component.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

[image: Microsoft OCR Library Error adding to Project]

I then found out from [the Nuget Page](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Ocr/) that the "Supported Platforms" are only **Windows Phone 8, Windows Phone 8.1, Windows 8.1 (Windows Store apps only).**

[image: microsoft ocr library nuget error]

But surely, there must be a way to use this **OCR dll** on the Server-side in an ASP.Net Application?

#### Does anyone know of a way to reference `Microsoft.Windows.Ocr` (/ `WindowsPreview.Media.Ocr.dll` ) Assembly on a server-side ASP.Net Web application like MV4 Web API and make use of the OCR Functionality in that assembly to take a photo image as input and extract the text content out of it ?** *If yes, please provide detailed instructions in your answer.*

Any "hacks" and/or Sample code would be much appreciated!!

Thank you!!

Comment: So ASP.NET MVC 4 or ASP.NET Web API?

Comment: that .dll is not a server library.  It is exclusive to Windows Phone and Windows 8.1 Store Client Apps.

Comment: @abatishchev Yes! AndrewCounts I understand. But wouldn't it somehow be possible? I tried various open source and commercial OCR Libraries. The open source ones are buggy and not updated, while commercial ones cost upwards of 1000 $ + ridiculous royalties.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I'm looking for OCR and I did find something over on code project that I'm about to try out. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10130/OCR-with-Microsoft-Office

Comment: Hi Shiva, FYI [Asprise OCR for C#, VB.NET SDK Component Library](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/c%23-sharp.net-ocr-api-overview.html) is royalty free.

Comment: you do realize mobile apps are written for a different hardware architecture than your PC? So in short, no.

Comment: what's hardware architecture got to do with OCR on an image file?

Comment: Is there any work solution?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10, the

> Microsoft.Windows.Ocr

has been moved to Universal Windows Platform. It is available as

> Windows.Media.Ocr

So you need to upgrade your VS 2015 with tools for Windows 10 enabled.

I did the following and Windows.Media.Ocr got added as a reference in my Web API.

1. In your Web API project's references right click any of the references and click View in Object Browser. Your Object browser will look something like this
   [image]
2. There is a '...' button right next to the "Browse: All components" Box. The tooltip reads "Edit Custom Component set".Click!
3. In the "Edit Custom Component Set" Box click the Browse Tab and Navigate to "C:/Program Files(x86)/Windows Kits/10/References/Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract/1.0.0.0" 
   and click the winmd file that results and click Add.
4. Hit Ok!
5. Now click icon that reads "Add to references in Selected Project in Solution Explorer"(It is the third button from the '...' button next to "Browse:"). You can see that Windows.Media.Ocr is available to use.

Note: The following works only with VS 2015 and windows 10. That too VS 2015 should be updated for [Universal Windows Platform](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/universal-windows-platform-vs.aspx)(UWP). Check [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/OCR) for a sample OCR.

Hope this helps. 
**Update**
It got imported into my reference but is failing to load though. Hope it provides some start for people.
Thanks!.

Comment: Thanks @Anish I'll check this out soon and let you know.

Comment: Do you have instructions on how to "upgrade your VS 2015 with tools for Windows 10 enabled"? I am looking at NuGet packages but not sure which one.

Comment: @Ewan - You can go to Control Panel -> Select VS2015 -> Click Change -> Click Modify - > Select Universal Windows Platform - Click Next/Finish. It will update your VS2015 for win dev.

Answer (score 5):

**You can Skip to Update 2 below for a working solution.**

IT WILL THROW A TYPE LOAD EXCEPTION. That being said I am posting because I am trying to do the same thing but can't  get the project to run. Here are some basic instructions on how to get the winrt api into your non windows app project.

http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2012/10/calling-winrt-from-windows-desktop-apps.html

Also don't try to reference the dll, reference instead the winmd file.

Here is a sample console app that references the ocr library but when you run the solution it throws the type load exception.(https://github.com/Xandroid4Net/MicrsoftOcrConsoleApp) It should be easily ported from a console app to and asp.net application. I don't know how to fix the type load exception maybe you can get farther than I can. Please post if you do find a solution.

#### UPDATE 1 (12/1/2014)

More digging revealed the following assembly binding error. Any idea how to set a package Id for a Process?

File:   WindowsPreview.Media.Ocr!WindowsPreview.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime.htm

File Contents:

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (12/1/2014 @ 11:48:01 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80073d54. The process has no package identity.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Users\Wesley\Documents\Dev\ConsoleApplication2\Program.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

BEGIN : Windows Runtime Type bind.
END   : The process has no package identity. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54)

#### Update 2 (12/03/2014)

This is a nasty workaround but it worked on my Windows 8.1 Surface Pro 3 tablet. The WebOcr is a webforms but it can easily be refactored for MVC

1) Download https://github.com/Xandroid4Net/CommandLineOcr. This is the psuedo store app.

2) Build and run the app. It will appear to do nothing. That is okay, it will update the registry with a new key that we will need.

3) Download https://github.com/Xandroid4Net/WebOcr.

4) Find OcrCommandLineCaller.cs in the Webocr project.

5) Locate the registry key at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\Some_Sort_Of_Guid_For_Your_APP\Server\App.App....\AppUserModelId

Refer to this SO question if you need more help finding the registry key. [IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925748/iapplicationactivationmanageractivateapplication-in-c)

6) Update the appActiveManager.ActivateApplication call in OcrCommandLineCaller.cs with the strange guid app identifier found in the registry key.

7) In default.aspx.cs replace the saveAsPath with the path on your machine. In the windows store app there is a static path represented by Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder. This is the path where I saved my images for simplicity.

8) Modify any of the code to your heart's content and let me know if you have any questions.

This is a very rough and nasty solution, but it does work.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying out your solution today. I somehow missed your Update 2 over the weekend...

Comment: @user3027550: I launched the app in visual studio and it launches successfully. However, There are no Server of ActivatableClassId keys. Why would this be?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, what error are you receiving?

Answer (score 3):

I have been using the MODI solution packaged with MS Office for a few years, and was pretty happy with it (it was free if you bought Office). I was rather disappointed when it was discontinued. 
I've tried Tesseract... I really wanted to like it, but found it slow and inaccurate for Dutch machine type of good quality... and like you, I could not justify spending anything north $200 for what was essentially a hobby project.

After a desperate search, someone on here pointed me at TOCR (a Transym product). An epiphany followed soon after. ;-)
I think I need to say at this point that I am not affiliated with Transym in any way, and yes, I paid the full price... **of 60 pounds!** (no typo... sixty quid), which, including VAT, worked out to 113 euros.

It is essentially meant for integrators (it includes a scan/viewer/OCR app, but that is merely meant as a demo - if you buy the license, you get its source code). The API is outdated (it is, as OCR engines go, quite a mature code base), but it is fast, stable, and unexpectedly accurate. Not as accurate as the DokuStar engine or other esoteric engines, but for my application (Dutch and ENglish machine type) it holds its own against various engines that are well north of $1000. Recognition accuracy on Dutch machine type is excellent (it doesn't do handwriting). 
In my opinion, in terms of value for money, it is simply ridiculously good. 
As to the API: I wrote a rudimentary .NET wrapper around it to suit my needs - this was done in a few evenings.

There is an eval version available on their web site (http://www.transym.com/index.htm). And no, I don't get any money if you do ;-)

Comment: your link: www.tocr.com is to a real estate site

Comment: I tested it out, and like any OCR it will depend on the font.  On the font I used it against (low res screen font) it often put 2 or 3 spaces between most words and completely messed up on data like dates or random characters.  It did acceptable on sentences.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to invoke the OCR from Web API by invoking the DLL from powershell. I found also that you cannot invoke this DLL in parallel.

It took me a few days, but here is the repo. Available both as nuget and web API with Windows docker https://github.com/MihaiTheCoder/ocr-all-in-one

I developed Web API project mostly for this question, so hopefully somebody will find it useful.

The powershell that is invoking Windows OCR is here: https://github.com/MihaiTheCoder/ocr-all-in-one/blob/master/Ocr.Wrapper/Resources/Get-Text-Win-OCR.ps1

It is a 2 stage process because the initialization of the OCR engine takes more time, and it is better to have it cached.

Comment: powershell api call works flawlessly. you rock mate!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, probably not worth your effort to try to use a library that is not supported on the platform you are targeting.

You could check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576652/how-to-programmatically-read-over-a-scanned-document-or-image) for some free alternatives.

Comment: I tried various open source (incl. Tessaract-OCR mentioned in your link) and commercial OCR Libraries. The open source ones are buggy and not updated, while commercial ones cost upwards of 1000 $ + ridiculous royalties. OCR API's are charging per scan, and it doesn't fit my needs since my App that will access the RESTful OCR Service I am building, is going to be free.

Comment: This one starts at $399: http://www.aspose.com/.net/ocr-component/pricing.aspx. Also check [componentsource](http://www.componentsource.com/features/scanning-ocr/net-components/index.html) for 43 more options.

Comment: Thank you NightOwl. The most popular ones on Compeonentsource are over $2,000. The aspose one has some royalty restrictions. That's the whole reason I am trying to get this Microsoft one to work. Because most of these commercial ones either 1) are way too expensive or 2) don't work properly (i evaluated trial versions for some) or 3) try to charge royalties for perpetual income for something that is very widely available...

Comment: I tried the aspose.com free trial version. Not sure if they have disabled features but it doesn't work at all! Even for a simple photo of a document, it extract garbage for the text from image OCR functionality.

Comment: @Shiva: Looking for the same: Have you found anything in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the UWP OCR API working on desktop app using uwpdesktop NuGet.

Install-Package uwpdesktop

You can then make calls to UWP APIs.

Answer (score -2):

I am not a lawyer, but my understanding is the the Microsoft end user license agreement for that library does **not allow** to use the Microsoft OCR Library for Windows Runtime in your scenario.

Specifically, read the second paragraph, where it forbids to use the software on a server in a production environment:

> "2.    INSTALLATION AND USE RIGHTS.
>
> a.    General. One user may install and use copies of the software to
>   design, develop, test and demonstrate your programs. **You may not use
>   the software on a server in a production environment**."

At the same time, they also restrict the run of the distributable code exclusively to Windows Store or Windows Phone:

> "3.    ADDITIONAL LICENSING REQUIREMENTS AND/OR USE RIGHTS.
>
> a.    Distributable Code. The software contains code that you are
>   permitted to distribute in programs you develop if you comply with the
>   terms below.
>
> i.     ..
>
> ii.    ..
>
> iii.   Distribution Restrictions. You may not
>
> ```
>       ..
> ```
>
> ·         **distribute Distributable Code to run on a platform other
>   than the Windows Store or Windows Phone**;"

The full EULA can be read at: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/windows_runtime_ocr_library_terms_of_use.htm

Comment: This EULA link is dead and it seems that it may no longer be in effect. https://ocr.space/blog/2015/10/microsoft-ocr-on-windows-server-2016.html